# HPC Boot Strapper - Error - Disabled SOA Runtime - ETW manifest install

Tags: azure, mpi, hpc

I am trying to disable SOA from the Azure HPC sample project. I have removed the line config.EnableSOA as instructed at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674347(v=vs.85).aspx
This causes the hpcbootstrapepr to fail, and the hpc job scheduler is not launched properly.

If I re-execute E:\plugins\HpcHeadNode\HPCPack\bin\hpcbootstrapper.exe the job scheduler installation will complete and I can execute MPI jobs.

I want to use MSMPI only and make the deployment as small as possible. (Currently around 56Mb)

Using SDK 1.8 and the latest AppConfigure project from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Windows-Azure-HPC-7d75eb26

```
9/24/2013 10:22:05 PM: Executing command: D:\Windows\System32\wevtutil.exe im E:\plugins\HpcHeadNode\HPCPack\bin\RuntimeEvents.man /rf:E:\plugins\HpcHeadNode\HPCPack\bin\BrokerBase.dll /mf:E:\plugins\HpcHeadNode\HPCPack\bin\BrokerBase.dll /pf:E:\plugins\HpcHeadNode\HPCPack\bin\BrokerBase.dll
9/24/2013 10:22:05 PM: Unhandled exception: Soa runtime ETW manifest installation failed with exit code 2.
Output:

Error:
The system cannot find the file specified.


9/24/2013 10:22:05 PM:    at HPCBootStrapper.Utils.ExecuteCommandInternal(String cmdPath, String cmdArgs, String actionDesc, Int32 errorToIgnore, Int32 retryErrorCode, Int32 retryTimes, Int32 retryIntervalMs, Int32 procTimeoutMs)
   at HPCBootStrapper.HpcSoa.InstallETWManifests()
   at HPCBootStrapper.HpcSoa.ConfigureSoa(List`1 modules)
   at HPCBootStrapper.HpcBootStrapper.BootStrap(List`1 modules)
   at HPCBootStrapper.HpcBootStrapper.Main(String[] args)
```

This re-execution resolves:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690643/windows-azure-hpc-scheduler-sample-no-such-host-is-known/18987644#18987644

Answer (score 0):

HPC Scheduler service (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Windows-Azure-HPC-7d75eb26) is deprecated.

The officially supported configuration is HPC Pack 2012 installed on a VM hosted on-premise or within Azure. This error is not present in this configuration.

See:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36054